# Library template does not show up as an App in another site collection

Tags: 2013, list-template

I'm trying to use a library template for another site collection.

I saved a document library as a template on Site collection A , downloaded that .stp file and uploaded that file on site collection B. However, when I try to add a library using that template, the saved template does not show up as an App. I checked and version and feature ID are same for both site collection. Any Ideas?

Comment: is the language same in both site collections ?

Comment: How do I check that?